# A minimal POSIX conformant operating system

Tags: distribution-choice, posix

For educational purposes, I'd like to start with a POSIX compliant base, including a shell, basic utilities, and an ANSI C compiler, then see what kind of environments I can build by putting packages together.

However, most minimal POSIX conformant operating systems I've come across seem to be embedded and/or proprietary. Are there any such open source systems I can easily run under Virtualbox?

I have searched around a little about building such an environment [from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/), but it seems like it's a lot of work to simply get a bootable/usable environment, much less a a POSIX compliant one. I might try my hands at building a POSIX OS someday, but I'd first like to be a bit more computer savvy beforehand.

Note:

I think I have heard somewhere that Linux is not completely POSIX conformant, but as long as I can compile and build some of the more common and essential open source tools (like wget and w3m), I would be pretty happy, whether or not it used the Linux kernel. Same goes for the other basic components I would imagine might come with the operating system (e.g. glibc)

Comment: When you see an issue with “proprietary”, I don't see where is the issue, as being proprietary does not impede POSIX conformance. Did you want to mean “commercial”?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

POSIX does not specify a complete operating system, so any POSIX-compliant OS will have commands that aren't in POSIX (like `init`, `mkfs`, `passwd`, …). But different OSes have different extensions, and GNU tools (found on non-embedded Linux systems) have a lot.

[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) is a set of command-line tools that is intended for embedded Linux systems. It contains most of the utilities and options mandated by POSIX (it's not complete, but it comes close). You can make a running Linux system with a bootloader, a Linux kernel, BusyBox, and [Dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) if you want to log in over SSH. Add [Gcc](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/) if you want to do development on the minimal system.

If you prefer to start from a full but small distribution, look at [MINIX 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX3). This is a small unix system intended for embedded systems and for teaching.

If you want a more easily extensible system, look at [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/). OpenBSD is focused on security and is conservative on features, but the core system does include major components such as Perl and Apache.

Comment: I believe [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) is more close to ANSI C/ISO C99 than GCC is, which would make it a better option for a C compiler in a strict POSIX environment avoiding non‑conforming features.